# Why does the absolute positioning (position:absolute) cannot be placed inside a static parent container?

Tags: css-position, absolute

I understand that the way CSS works, the element with absolute positioning finds the closest parent container that is not static. I just want to know why this is the case? Why are absolute-positioned elements not allowed to go inside a static parent container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML elements are positioned static by default and static positioned elements are not affected by the top, bottom, left, and right properties so an element with position: `static` is not positioned in any special way; it is always positioned according to the normal flow of the page.

An `absolute` positioned element will position itself relative to the nearest positioned ancestor and the reason why it can't be relative to a static element parent is because otherwise absolute wouldn't be able to position with respect to anything other than the element's immediate pareny and it will have to apply calculations on every element instead of being able to take just shorter paths for static positioning elements.

The use of `static` positioned elements allows you to have arbitrary elements containers and this let's you have an element to be positionable relative to the  element container you wish and not neccerly the intermediate parent.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! God bless you.